# EPPLUS - Charts not updating after table grows

Tags: excel, epplus

I have an Excel file with a table and several charts created from data in the table. I need the charts to take any new data when the table grows. It works fine if I work from Excel, obviously (i.e. when I add a new row, the charts make room for the new data and when the numbers are added, the charts show the changes).

But I need to do it programmatically with Epplus. I've managed to add a row to the table and have it update all the formulae in it properly, but the charts are not updated.

Any idea of why this is? Is it a known limitation of EPPlus? 
Or do I have to traverse all the charts and update the data series for each?